# Warning: Undefined variable $error

Tags: php, mysql, datos

Cordial Saludo.

Estoy estudiando y practicando PHP. Cree un formulario, para que se muestren en la misma página, hasta ahí bien, incluso funciona el código. Me encuentro en la validación del formulario, y al momento de recargar la página me aparece que la variable $error no está definida, cuando la tengo definida en el archivo register.php. Por tanto no puedo seguir con la validación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que ese error no aparezca?
register.php

```
<?php
require "conex.php";

if (isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
// Se envía la información
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $pais = $_POST['pais'];
    $ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $correoAlterno = $_POST['correoAlterno'];    
    $error = array();

    if ($nombre === "") {
        $error[0] = "El campo 'Nombre' no debe ir vacio";
    } else if ($apellido === "") {
        $error[1] = "El campo 'Apellido' no debe ir vacio";
    }else if ($pais === "") {
        $error[2] = "El campo 'País' no debe ir vacio";
    }else if ($ciudad === "") {
        $error[3] = "El campo 'Ciudad' no debe ir vacio";
    }else if ($telefono === "") {
        $error[4] = "El campo 'Teléfono' no debe ir vacio";
    }else if ($correo === "") {
        $error[5] = "El campo 'Dirección de correo electrónico' no debe ir vacio";
    } else {
        if (validarCorreo($correo, $conex)) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES(0,";
            $sql .= "'".$nombre."', '".$apellido."', ";
            $sql .= "'".$pais."', '".$ciudad."', ";
            $sql .= "'".$telefono."', '".$correo."')";

            if (mysqli_query($conex, $sql)) {
                
                header("location:gracias.php");
            } else {
                echo "Ooopps, Hubo un error, Intentalo nuevamente";
            }
        } else {
            $error[7] = "Lo siento, el correo principal ya se encuentra registrado";
            echo $error[7];
        }
        
    }
    
}
function validarCorreo($correo, $conex) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE correo='".$correo."'";
    $r = mysqli_query($conex, $sql);
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    $bandera = ($n==0)? true : false;
    return $bandera;
}
?>
```

cuenta.php Estoy usando Bootstrap.

```
<?php
require "php/register.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-2">

<h2>Crea tu propia cuenta</h2>

<?php                                                    

if ( is_countable($error) && count($error) > 0) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
    foreach ($error as $key => $valor) {
        echo '<strong>* '.$valor.'</strong>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>                                                  

<form action="php/register.php" method="post" class="register">

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_email">Nombre Completo<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="nombre" id="nombre"/>
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_email">Apellido Completo<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="apellido" id="apellido"/>
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_email">País<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="pais" id="pais" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_email">Ciudad<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad"/>
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_email">Teléfono<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="tel" class="input-text" name="telefono" id="telefono"/>
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_email">Dirección de correo electrónico<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="input-text" name="correo" id="email" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="password">Ingresa una contraseña<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text"  name="password" id="password" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="password">confirme la contraseña<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input  type="password"  class="input-text" name="password2" id="password2" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row"><input type="submit" class="button" name="register" value="Crear" /></p>



</form>

</div><!-- .col-2 -->
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias de a la persona que me colabore.

Comment: Mueve `$error = array();` arriba de `if (isset($_POST['nombre'])) {...}`, saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Cris223511.dev funciono perfectamente.